# How to plot one dataframe column against all other columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this.

```
Heat_map <- c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
city1 <-  c(0,1,1,1,0)
city2 <-  c(0,1,0,0,1)
city3 <-  c(0,1,1,0,0)
city4 <-  c(1,1,0,0,0)

city_df <- cbind(Heat_map, city1, city2, city3, city4)
city_df <- as.data.frame(city_df)
```

I am trying to plot (ggplot or any kind of plot) to show relation between first column, that is heat_map and rest of the columns. I have spend enough time and experiments but I couldn't find a suitable approach for plotting using all columns against one column from same dataframe.

Comment: `matplot(city_df[1], city_df[-1], type="l", lty=1, pch=19)` maybe? `?matplot` generally fits exactly with what you describe wanting to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic "wide to long" problem: *i.e.* it's easier to plot if the cities are in one column (named `city`) and the value for each city in another (`value`). You can do that using `gather` from the `tidyr` package.

Then you can use `ggplot2` and either `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to make a chart for each city.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

city_df %>% 
  gather(city, value, -Heat_map) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Heat_map, value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~city)
```

Result:
[image]